# NumPy empty() array not giving random float after defining normal NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I was using the NumPy `np.empty()` to get an array with a random value, but it doesn't work when I define a normal `np.array()` before.

Here is the two functions I used:

```
import numpy as np

def create_float_array(x):
    return np.array([float(x)])

def get_empty_array():
    return np.empty((), dtype=np.float).tolist()
```

Just to test the `get_empty_array()`, I wrote in the console:

```
>>> get_empty_array() # Should return a random float
>>> 0.007812501848093234
```

I was pleased with the result, so I tried this, but it didn't work the way I wanted:

```
>>> create_float_array(3.1415) # Create a NumPy array with the float given
>>> array([3.1415])
>>> get_empty_array() # Should return another random value in a NumPy array
>>> 3.1415
```

I am not too sure as to why creating a NumPy array affects the `np.empty()` method from giving a random value. Apparently, it gives the same value as the value in the np.array(), in this case, `3.1415`.

Note that I chose to leave the shape of the `np.empty()` to nothing for testing purposes, but in reality it would have some shape.

Finally, I know this is not the correct way of getting random values, but I need to use the `np.empty()` in my program, but don't exactly know why this behaviour occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify the point:

`np.empty` is not giving truly random values. The [offical NumPy documentation states](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) that it will contain "uninitialized entries" or "arbitary data":

> ### `numpy.empty(shape, dtype=float, order='C')`
>
> Return a new array of given shape and type, without initializing entries.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Returns:
>
> out : *ndarray*
>
> Array of uninitialized (arbitrary) data of the given shape, dtype, and order. Object arrays will be initialized to None.

So what does uninitialized or arbitrary mean? To understand that you have to understand that when you create an object (any object) you need to ask someone (that someone can be the NumPy internals, the Python internals or your OS) for the required amount of memory.

So when you create an empty array NumPy asks for memory. The amount of memory for a NumPy array will be some overhead for the Python object and a certain amount of memory to contain the values of the array. That memory may contain anything. So an "uninitialized value" means that it simply contains whatever is in that memory you got.

What happened here is just a coincidence. You created an array containing one float, then you printed it, then it is destroyed again because you noone kept a reference to it (although that is CPython specific, other Python implementations may not free the memory immediately, they just free it eventually). Then you create an empty array containing one float. The amount of memory for the second array is identical to the amount of memory just released by the first memory. Here's where the coincidence comes in: So maybe something (NumPy, Python or your OS) decided to give you the same memory location again.

Comment: I read about `np.empty` and found this: numpy.empty(shape, dtype = float, order = ‘C’) : Returns a new array of given shape and type, with random values. So does it not give random values? Site: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-empty-python/

Comment: @SurajKothari The official NumPy documentation states for`empty`: "return a new array of given shape and type, without initializing entries." (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html). However even your version is true. It just wasn't a "good random value" it is just "any random value that happened to be there already".

Comment: What does it mean if I dumped the array

Comment: @SurajKothari because it gets garbage collected after you leave the function. You don't assign that array to any name in the global scope, so the memory is freed. It then gets reallocated to your new array that happens to be the same shape

Comment: You did not keep an reference to the array `create_float_array(3.1415)`. WIth "dumped" I meant that you created it but since you don't keep a reference to it Python will (immediately or eventually) garbage collect it. For CPython it is immediate, so it's created, printed, and immediately destroyed again.

Comment: If it is 'destroyed', then how comes np.empty() still references it?

Comment: @SurajKothari It references the same memory, not the object. The first array is (from the point of view of NumPy, Python and your OS) deleted. I updated the answer to include some of the points mentioned in the comments here.